# QGLBuffer and VBO

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt4, vbo

I have a problem with QGLBuffer. I'm trying to implement a dynamic VBO with QT + Opengl.

In the .h file

```
struct CVert {
   float x;                                                 
   float y;                                                 
};
...

typedef struct CVert CVert;     
CVert* m_data;
QGLBuffer* m_bufferData;
int m_size;
```

in the .cpp

Constructor.

```
m_size = numberOfVertex;
m_bufferData = new QGLBuffer(QGLBuffer::VertexBuffer);
m_bufferData->create();
m_bufferData->bind();
m_bufferData->setUsagePattern(QGLBuffer::DynamicDraw);
m_bufferData->allocate(2*sizeof(float)* p_size);
m_data = (CVert*)m_bufferData->map (QGLBuffer::ReadWrite);
```

In the execution of the program I change some m_data values

```
m_data[pos].x = X1
m_data[pos].y = y1
```

In the draw method.

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
if (m_bufferData->bind ()) {
   glVertexPointer( 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, (char *) NULL );;
   glDrawArrays( GL_LINES, 0,m_size );
   glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}
```

But nothig it's being drawn.
I've checked that m_data is not null, and m_bufferData->bind() returns true.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i've solved. Every time i've to edit the VBO. 
I have to

```
m_data = (CVert*)data->map (QGLBuffer::ReadWrite); 
m_data[pos].x = X1;
m_data[pos].y = y1 
data->unmap ();
```

it's doesn't work if I map only once in the constructor

Comment: That's made clear in the [`glMapBuffer` docs](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glMapBuffer.xml): "A mapped data store must be unmapped with glUnmapBuffer before its buffer object is used. Otherwise an error will be generated by any GL command that attempts to dereference the buffer object's data store."